# If statement does not work when condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
var count = 2;
var decrementAmount = 1;

function reduceVariable() {
    count -= decrementAmount;
}

$("#button").click(function() {
    reduceVariable();
});

if (count == 0) {
    $("#avrageReactionTime").html("Hello");
};
```

When i click my button twice the div that has the id avrageReactionTime does not change to have the text hello. Why do i have this problem...

Comment: add your `if` to `click` handler :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you test once, instead of testing every time the counter changes.

You must put the `if` inside the event handler :

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  reduceVariable();
  if (count==0) {    
     $("#avrageReactionTime").html("Hello");
  }
});
```

Note that properly indenting your code makes it obvious.

Comment: I will add that's because JS is not executed line by line, so the if sentence in the original source code is executed the first time the JS file is loaded.

Comment: Yes, it's possible OP thought some part would be declarative, instead of imperative.